# Budget laptop for exams (<150$)?

Tags: laptop, cheap

I would like to buy hundred of very low budget laptops for a programming exam. The requirements are:

- Screen > 12''
- User storage < 100 MB
- OS POSIX compliant
- Keyboard
- Trackpad
- Wi-Fi
- Ram > 1 GB
- Camera (to identify a student)
- Price < 150$

Most of the very cheap laptops I found are already too powerful. For example on `wish` there is a 150$ laptop with 64G SSD, Bluetooth, 2GHz...

Where can I find this kind of very cheap computer?

If I think in terms of independent components I can imagine a working product for less than 100$:

- Raspberry Pi: 30$
- SDcard 16GB: 5$
- Power supply with battery: 20$
- Keyboard: 5$
- Mouse: 5$
- Screen: 30$
- Case: 5$

The goal is to run a Docker client and a web browser that could connect to a repl.it or run vscode.

Comment: Do you really want ten times as much  RAM as storage?

Comment: This is the minimum I need. These laptops will be only used for exams and I don't know any student that can write more than 100 kB of code in 4 hours.

Comment: Would you not have trouble storing a modern operating system and a web browser on a device with 100 MB of storage, assuming you could find one?

Comment: 100 MB is the user storage,not the disk size